# Multiple condition with two table data in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table 
One '**student**' table :

```
    +-----------+--------------+------+
    | Field     | Type         | Null | 
    +-----------+--------------+------+
    | studentid | int(11)      | NO   | 
    | classid   | varchar(128) | YES  |  
    | name      | varchar(128) | YES  |
    | email     | varchar(128) | YES  |
    +-----------+--------------+------+
```

Second '**daily**' table :

```
    +-----------+---------+------+
    | Field     | Type    | Null | 
    +-----------+---------+------+
    | dailyid   | int(11) | NO   | 
    | classid   | int(11) | YES  |  
    | studentid | int(11) | YES  |
    | mark      | int(11) | YES  |
    | dailydate | date    | YES  |
    +-----------+---------+------+
```

i have two value classid and date. Now i want to make below table with some condition :

```
    +-----------+
    | Field     |
    +-----------+
    | studentid |
    | classid   |
    | name      |
    | email     |
    | mark      |
    | dailydate | 
    +-----------+
```

i want all student data in particular class as given classid with **daily** table mark in given date. if given date have not data then get all student with null value.

for example :

```
    +-----------+---------+-------+-------+------+-----------+
    | studentid | classid | name  | email | mark | dailydate |
    +-----------+---------+-------+-------+------+-----------+
    |     1     |    1    | shipu | s@g.c | null |    null   |
    |     2     |    1    | dipok | d@g.c | null |    null   |
    +-----------+---------+-------+-------+------+-----------+
```

I try with below sql :

```
    Select s.*,d.mark,d.dailydate
    From student as s left join daily as d on 
    s.studentid=d.studentid and s.classid=d.classid 
    where s.classid=1 and d.dailydate='2014-11-11'
```

Comment: The query looks ok. What is going wrong?

Comment: when i add date condition then it's show me nothing if there is not data .... i i want to get student all data with null value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
Select s.*, d.mark, d.dailydate
From student s left join
     daily d 
     on s.studentid = d.studentid and s.classid = d.classid 
 where s.classid = 1 and d.dailydate = '2014-11-11'
```

The condition on `date` is undoing the `left join`.  You need to move it to the `on` clause:

```
Select s.*, d.mark, d.dailydate
From student s left join
     daily d 
     on s.studentid = d.studentid and s.classid = d.classid and
        d.dailydate = '2014-11-11' 
 where s.classid = 1
```